# Material UI DialogTitle cutomization with Styled is not working

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, dialog, customization

I am using the styled component for [material ui Dialog](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/dialog/).

I am trying to override the default css of `<DialogTitle>`. Unfortunately this is not working.

`<StyledDialogTitle>{"Delete Task"}</StyledDialogTitle>`

```
export const StyledDialogTitle = styled(DialogTitle)(() => ({
  "& .MuiDialogTitle-root": {
    padding: 2,
    backgroundColor: "red",
  },
}));
```

Below is the part of the generated html

```
<h2 class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-h6 MuiDialogTitle-root css-1glgnft-MuiTypography-root-MuiDialogTitle-root" id=":r27:">Delete Category</h2>
```

[image]